# copytree with loop in softlinks

Tags: python

Is there any way to detect softlink loops and omit copying them?

I have a directory that contain the softlink to himself. and I want to copy the folder recursively (including the meta data for all softlinks) except the one who create loop. it there any way to do so?

This is the structure of the director

```
makedir testdir
echo "hello world" > removeme.txt 
cd testdir
ln TOPDIR ../testdir -s
ln -s ../removeme.txt slnk
```

so the directory would be:

```
ls test_dir/ -l 
total 64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Dec  7 09:31 slnk -> ../removeme.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Dec  6 12:46 TOPDIR -> ../test_dir
```

this is the python:

```
from os.path import realpath
import shutil
shutil.copytree(realpath('testdir'),'removeme_softlink')
```

It copies the folder into itself recursively until it raises exception. The error would like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./m.py", line 10, in <module>
   shutil.copytree(realpath(fileName),'removeme_softlink');
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/shutil.py", line 173, in copytree
   raise Error, errors
  shutil.Erro:
  /test_dir/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR', 'removeme_softlink/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR/TOPDIR', "
  [Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links: ....
```

Comment: Use [`os.path.realpath()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) to unwrap your links and check against the actual path.

Comment: does not work. I  have edited the question so that it is more clearly shown the problem.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

By using `realpath()` [from docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath):

> Return the canonical path of the specified filename, **eliminating any symbolic links** encountered in the path

*EDIT:*

I've done some more research and it seems this could be not solvable. All in all files are only sequences of bytes on your disk and what makes these bytes meaningful is your operating system. In particular symlinks are files with very arbitrary sequences of character which do not even need to be paths to existing files! When using methods like `read()` `open()` under your language layer it's your operating system that handles input/output operations on files. If it can't handle it, probably nothing won't and you'll have to make some workarounds like checking whether your symbolic link points to itself. I recommend [this discussion](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2011-02/msg00002.html):

> Creating a symlink that contains the name of the current file may have
>   a use.  I do not know.  But there isn't any content scanning of the
>   contents of the symlink file.  Almost certainly someone someplace is
>   using such a value as a flag of some sort.  If you try to open such a
>   symlink the kernel will redirect back to itself creating a loop that
>   will exceed the configured loop count and be detected.

Comment: does not work. I  have edited the question so that it is more clearly shown the problem